# C++ returned array loses it's values depending on if any new array is declared or not. Its losing it if yes

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters

I wrote a simple c++ program where i am getting a simple float Array from a function. Then I call a function where the generated Array is a parameter of. I print the first value of the Array through the function. It works! BUT when i am declaring another array in the function before i print the value from the first array, the printed value is not the expected one. MAGIC!

CODE THAT DOESN'T WORK:

```
#include <iostream>;

float* getArray() {
    float Array[] = { 4 };
    return Array;
}

void compute(float* Array) {

    bool newArray[1];
    float content = Array[0]; //breakpoint: content will be -107374176.
    std::cout << content;

}

int main() {

    float* Array = getArray();
    compute(Array);
}
```

OUTPUT: **-1.07374e+08**

When removing the line "bool newArray[1];" (line 10) the code starts to work.

OUTPUT: **4**

Test it your self! Can someone explain me why this happens?

Comment: The compiler should be giving you a warning telling you not to return arrays from functions. Study the dup for more info.

Comment: I get this running error `Program returned: 139` different from what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main` function has a bug. It passes a pointer to `Array` to `compute`, which dereferences it. But `Array` is out of scope at this point since its scope ends when `getArray` ends. So you are trying to access an object that no longer exists. That is undefined behavior and produces completely unpredictable results.

Arguably, `getArray` also has a bug since it always returns a pointer to an object that no longer exists. So there is no way to use it. Whether or not that's a bug depends on what the caller is supposed to be able to do with the returned value which cannot be determined due to the lack of comments.